# Refer to a column by it's title

Tags: java, swt

I have a table which currently has 11 columns.
As the program evolves, I find myself needing to add more columns.

The problem with how I do that, is that if I add a new column in position 5, I need to then change the code that sets data in columns 6,7,8 etc.

I set the column headers this way:

```
String[] titles = { "Date", "Condition", "Weight", "Pos", "Distance",
            "Margin", "Time", "200m", "PIR", "Jockey", "Track" };

for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
     TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
     column.setText(titles[i]);
}
```

So at the moment I am doing:

```
item.setText(0, meetingDate[i]);
item.setText(1, trackCondition[i]);
item.setText(2, weight[i]);
item.setText(3, position[i]);
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
item.setText(colMeetingdate, meetingDate[i]);
item.setText(colTrackCond, trackCondition[i]);
item.setText(colWeight, weight[i]);
item.setText(colPos, position[i]);
```

Is there a standard way to name/refer to columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this. The easiest solution I can think of is to keep your column headers in a `List` (let's call it `tableHeaders`) and insert/remove as needed.

To get your index, just do:

```
int index = tableHeaders.indexOf("headerString");

if(index != -1)
    item.setText(index, blabla[i]);
```

---

This solution assumes that the user can't reorder your table columns.

Comment: Thank you. Searching up .indexof I'm now using `item.setText(Arrays.asList(titles).indexOf("Date"),meetingDate[i]);` to set the data. A bit lengthy, but it works.

Comment: @MarioCappellano Great, but please convert the array *only once* to a `List` instead of doing it each time.

Comment: Hmm, so: `List<String> columns = Arrays.asList(titles);` just once, then for each column: `item.setText(columns.indexOf("Date"), meetingDate[i]);`

Comment: @MarioCappellano Exactly!

Comment: Thanks heaps, appreciate it!